# How to make a RecycleView with different view types in python Kivy

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy

I have a recycleview which should have 4 different view types and i really don't know how to do that i tried to use the same view in the kv file then in the py in the view class i have dynamically added the view type that i really want but it didn't work. My code:

```
<FavsView>:
   viewclass: 'FavBox'
   RecycleBoxLayout:
      default_size: None, 440
      default_size_hint: 1, None
      size_hint_y: None
      height: self.minimum_height
      orientation: 'vertical'
<FavBox>:
   content: content
   BoxLayout:
      id: content

class FavsView(RecycleView):
   boss = ObjectProperty()
   diaryboxes = {}
   musicboxes = {}
   videoboxes = {}
   boxes = {}

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(FavsView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.data = [{'name': 'test1', 'ind': 0, 'boss': self, 'typ': 'diary'},
                 {'name': 'test2', 'ind': 1, 'boss': self, 'typ': 'image'},
                 {'name': 'test3', 'ind': 2, 'boss': self, 'typ': 'music'},
                 {'name': 'test4', 'ind': 3, 'boss': self, 'typ': 'music'},
                 {'name': 'test5', 'ind': 4, 'boss': self, 'typ': 'video'},
                 {'name': 'test6', 'ind': 5, 'boss': self, 'typ': 'video'}
                 ]
class FavBox(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
   boss = ObjectProperty()
   loa = 0
   content = ObjectProperty()

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(FavBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      Clock.schedule_interval(self.up, 1)

   def up(self, *args):
      if self.loa == 0:
         if self.typ == 'diary':
            d = Factory.DiaryBox(ind=self.ind)
            d.boss = self.boss
            self.content.add_widget(d)
         elif self.typ == 'image':
            d = Factory.ImageBox()
            d.boss = self.boss
            self.content.add_widget(d)
         elif self.typ == 'music':
            d = Factory.MusicBox()
            d.boss = self.boss
            self.content.add_widget(d)
         elif self.typ == 'video':
            d = Factory.VideoBox()
            d.boss = self.boss
            self.content.add_widget(d)
         self.loa = 1
```

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question. If you've solved your own problem, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a scrollview with a boxlayout, then add those childs to this boxlayout